# Download Marketing Cloud's Report data

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, ftp, tracking-extract

I'm new at SalesForce and probably don't know enough yet to tell if this is possible or complete nonsense.

I was wondering if I can **extract data** from a **Campaign Tracking Report** without the need of exporting it to FTP and then downloading (since I intend to make this export automatic). The report in question is the **"Account Send Summary"**.

I'm currently downloading it manually in Exact Target, and then using a PHP script to insert its contents in my Data Base. It would be nice if I could get these informations with SOAP requests, directly from the platform.

Thanks for the time, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use Automation Studio's Report Activity to automatically have a report exported to the FTP as CSV.  Once it's on the FTP, you could use an Import Activity to import it into a Data Extension, which is then accessible via the API.